# Out of memory with PhpStorm 2017.2.2 and JRE included (x64 version)

Tags: java, windows, windows-10, phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.2

**I have the famous "Out of Memory" warning in my PhpStorm.**

[image]

It appeared suddenly and now I can't use PhpStorm because the warning appears when PhpStorm starts. I try to change a lot of time the value of `-Xmx` but the warning is always here. I try also to change value in my `vmoptions` file.

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx1000m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

But nothing change. I definitely can't use PhpStorm. 
My free space memory in my windows system is good (2Go free after all tools running).

- What is the best most possible value for `-Xmx` ?
- What is the best JRE version for PhpStorm2017.2.2 ?
- Can I modify the `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize` ?
- What is the best value for `-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize` ?

Comment: General info: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties and comments

Answer (score 2):

1) Try to set it for 1500 - that's totally fine to have it this size.

2) Best JRE is bundled JRE (the one that comes with PhpStorm distribution)

3) You can but it's not advised to.

4) XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize could be left with a default value

The issue itself is probably caused by `vendor` and `node_modules` folders: try to mark them as excluded and add them in "Include paths" instead at File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP

Comment: I don't have a node_modules directory but vendor yes. I don't exclude this directory because I can't use PHPStorm.

Comment: Please be more specific: why can't you use PhpStorm? Doesn't it start? Does it freeze at project opening?